# Java System Level deployment Malformed deployment.config file

Tags: java, installation, config, java-web-start, system-administration

I am trying to install Java jre 1.8u31 from the command line. I am using system level install configuration by using the deployment.config file and deployment.properties. 
  [image: Batch script for install java jre]

I have tried the following:

```
deployment.system.config=file\:C\:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
```

I have also tried the following

```
deployment.system.config=file:///C:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
```

I have swapped the entries around in hopes of getting a better error describing what I am doing wrong.  I have also made the first line blank in the deployment.config file.  I have googled and tried all examples I could find online.  In all the cases, I am being presented a dialog box with an error that states the deployment.config file's line 1 is malformed.

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Russ

I have tried all of these formats:
[image]

Comment: Can anyone help or suggest a possible solution, please?

Comment: I have looked at the event log trying to determine if there are any O/S issues surfacing.   I saw none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the install to work correctly.  What I did was put the deployment.config file in the C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment directory.  The property in the file was setup as so:

```
deployment.system.config=file\:C\:\\Sup\\Java\\UPGRADE\\Deployment\\deployment.properties
```

The exceptionlist file was in the same directory as the deployment.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The path you have given should be in below format

```
deployment.system.config=file:/C:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.proper‌​ties
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I tried this.  It did now work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Is not needed to explicitly say to the installer to look at it if you are using the default system wide config location. Simply deploy the config files in the directory

```
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment
```

and Java is going to load it. If that path doesn't exists create it.

From the Oracle Java deploy guide:
21.1.2 System Level

The deployment.config file is used for specifying the system-level deployment.properties in the infrastructure. By default no deployment.config file exists, so no system-wide deployment.properties file exists. If the deployment.config file exists, it is located in one of the directories shown in the following table.

Source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html